# Reset Local Admin User on VM using AzureRM Rest api

Tags: rest, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I'm using the AzureRM rest api to communicate to the hypervisor.  One of the things I need to do is to reset the local admin password on a VM, however I can't figure out how to reset it.

Comment: Do you have any updates about this thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use the [Virtual Machine Extensions REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachineextensions#VirtualMachineExtensions_CreateOrUpdate) to do that. It works correctly for me. Following is my detail test info.

1.We need to get the [authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#use-the-access-token-to-access-the-resource) in the request header

```
Authorization:Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUz.......
Content-Type:application/json
```

2.Add the following info in the request body

```
{
  "properties": {
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
    "type": "VMAccessAgent",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "settings": {
      "UserName": "local admin"  //your local admin
    },
    "protectedSettings": {
      "Password": "your reset passord" //match the password policy
    }
  },
  "location": "East Asia"
}
```

3. Send the http request  with Fiddler.

[image]

4 . Successfully remote the VM with reset password.

We also can reset our local admin password in the Azure portal.

[image]

Comment: from the screen shot I see you are using the extension named tomtest, where do you get that name?

Comment: We can use the extension name as we like, if it is not existing, then will create new one for us. And the http method is `Put`.

Comment: If there is any concern about this thread, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Is it possible to make a request to Reset Password using App Registration? I have created a question in SO based on your response. But couldn't make it to work for me yet.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66912515/permissions-to-change-azure-vm-local-admin-password-using-app-registration

Comment: I was able to resolve my issue by actually setting exact extension name: `enablevmaccess`, so my final URL was like this: `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/MySubscr/resourceGroups/MyRG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/MyVM/extensions/enablevmaccess?api-version=2020-12-01`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Azure .NET SDK, which has a wrapper for the [create or update call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.ivirtualmachineextensionsoperations#Microsoft_Azure_Management_Compute_IVirtualMachineExtensionsOperations_BeginCreateOrUpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync_System_String_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Management_Compute_Models_VirtualMachineExtension_System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_List_System_String___System_Threading_CancellationToken_).

I tried and ran into an issue where the VM extension request went through fine and was installed successfully, but the password was not updated.

After attaching fiddler, I saw that my dynamic objects for `settings` and `protectedSettings` were not getting properly serialized by the library. The solution was to pass a dictionary down to the `VirtualMachineExtensions()` constructor instead.

Before:

```
proxy.VirtualMachineExtensions.BeginCreateOrUpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync(                                
                "<resource group>", 
                "<vm name>", 
                "<you name it>",
                new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.VirtualMachineExtension(
                    location: "westus",
                    publisher: "Microsoft.Compute",
                    virtualMachineExtensionType: "VMAccessAgent",
                    typeHandlerVersion: "2.0",
                    autoUpgradeMinorVersion: true,
                    settings: new
                    {
                        UserName: "<username>" 
                    },
                    protectedSettings: new
                    {
                        Password: "<password>" 
                    }));
```

After:

```
proxy.VirtualMachineExtensions.BeginCreateOrUpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync(                                
                "<resource group>", 
                "<vm name>", 
                "<you name it>",
                new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.VirtualMachineExtension(
                    location: "westus",
                    publisher: "Microsoft.Compute",
                    virtualMachineExtensionType: "VMAccessAgent",
                    typeHandlerVersion: "2.0",
                    autoUpgradeMinorVersion: true,
                    settings: new Dictionary<string, string>()
                    {
                        { "UserName", "<username>" }
                    },
                    protectedSettings: new Dictionary<string, string>()
                    {
                        {"PassWord", "<password>" }
                    }));
```