# Permissions to change Azure VM Local Admin Password using App Registration

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41606905/51230) answer where author shows how to change local admin password on the VM. I'm wondering what can I do to make this request call using App Registration account in Active Directory. What permissions do I need to give (and how) to this App Registration?

I'm using MSAL to get access token like this (in Python):

```
def az_get_access_token(client_id, authority, secret, default_scope):
    # Create a preferably long-lived app instance which maintains a token cache.
    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        client_id,
        authority=authority,
        client_credential=secret,
        # token_cache=...  # Default cache is in memory only.
        # To learn how to use SerializableTokenCache from
        #   https://msal-python.rtfd.io/en/latest/#msal.SerializableTokenCache
    )

    # Get access token
    result = app.acquire_token_silent(scopes=[default_scope], account=None)

    if not result:
        logging.debug("No suitable token exists in cache. Let's get a new one from AAD.")
        result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=[default_scope])

    if 'access_token' not in result:
        logging.error('Azure error: %s, description: %s' % (result['error'], result['error_description']))
        raise Exception

    access_token = result['access_token'] # JWT access token

    return access_token
```

And then making a call to the rest like this:

```
access_token = az_get_access_token(client_id, authority, app_secret, default_scope)

vm_pwd_change_payload = {
    'properties': {
        'publisher': 'Microsoft.Compute',
        'type': 'VMAccessAgent',
        'typeHandlerVersion': '2.0',
        'autoUpgradeMinorVersion': True,
        'settings': {
            'UserName': local_admin_user_name
        },
        'protectedSettings': {
            'Password': local_admin_new_password
        }
    },
    'location': "West US"
}

vm_pwd_update_change_resp = requests.put(
    'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%s/resourceGroups/%s/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/%s?api-version=2020-12-01' % (subscriptionId, resourceGroupName, vmName),
    headers={
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },

    data=json.dumps(vm_pwd_change_payload)
)

if not vm_pwd_update_change_resp.ok:
    print("Reason: %s" % vm_pwd_update_change_resp.reason)
    print("\t%s" % vm_pwd_update_change_resp.text)
else:
    print("CHANGED!!!!!!")
```

(Also, not sure what to put in `authority` and in the `scope`)

Comment: Try `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{teannt id}` as the `authority`. And for permission, since Application permission for Azure rest API in app registration is not available (it's gray out), we can assign RBAC role to the App Registration account  for the VM. Detailed steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal. Find the VM -> Access Control -> Add -> Add role assignment -> select a role (for example **Contributor**) and enter the name of your App Registration.

Comment: How about scope? What value should be entered there?

Comment: I'm getting error `{"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":"Authentication failed."}}` is that because I'm not specifying correct scope? Here is what I have for scope: `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`.

Comment: `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` is for Microsoft Graph. To call Azure Rest API, you can try`https://management.azure.com/` for v1.0 or `https://management.azure.com/.default` for v2.0. MASL should use V2.0, so it's probably `https://management.azure.com/.default`. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you! That helped. After this I had to overcome one more issue, had to change URL to the following:                 `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%s/resourceGroups/%s/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/%s/extensions/enablevmaccess?api-version=2020-12-01` (note: extensions/enablevmaccess)

Comment: Great! I will summarize the comments in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{teannt id}` as the `authority` and `https://management.azure.com/.default` as the `scope`.

For permission, since Application permission for Azure rest API in app registration is not available (it's gray out), we can assign RBAC role to the App Registration account for the VM. Detailed steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal).

Find the VM -> **Access Control** -> **Add** -> **Add role assignment** -> select a role (for example **Contributor**) and enter the name of your App Registration.

As you found, after that you have to change URL to the following: `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%s/resourceGroups/%s/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/%s/extensions/enablevmaccess?api-version=2020-12-01`.